# Finding timer in program process C#

Tags: c#

I have been reading the memory of a program using Cheat Engine. I found the timer, but I can't convert it to readable time. This is in 4 Byte, anything else I try gives me gibberish.

1509949440 = 9:00

2030043136 = 12:06

16777215 = 0:00

2868903936 = 17:12

2801795072 = 16:42

Any equation or function in C# I can use to convert these long numbers back to Minutes:Seconds format?

Comment: I think this might just be a programming thing, not really restricted to a specific language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found the answer after taking LOTS of guesses...

```
uint oddTimer = 1509949440;
double trueTimer = (oddTimer / 256^3) * 0.1;
return (uint)Math.Ceiling((double)trueTimer);
```

This returns 9:00

EDIT: Also, when pulling the oddTimer from memory, I have to remember to set it to a ulong because of the amount of digits given can break a normal int32.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with a programming language. It's just mathematics. Let's bring your list into a order and show the numbers in hex numbers and anything should get quite obvious:

```
Time      Decimal       Hex
---------------------------------
00:00       16777215    00FF FFFF
09:00     1509949440    5A00 0000
12:06     2030043136    7900 0000
16:42     2801795072    A700 0000
17:12     2868903936    AB00 0000
```

Here are some the differences break down:

```
From     To       Time Diff     Hex Diff    Hex Diff / Minute
-------------------------------------------------------------
17:12    16:42    0:30          400 0000    22 2222
12:06    09:00    3:06         1F00 0000    2A AAAA
09:00    00:00    9:00         5900 0001    2A 314D
17:12    09:00    8:12         5100 0000    2A 2576
```

As you can see by the numbers the diff per minute is jittering. This can be explained by the fact that the number internally has a higher resolution (what you see in memory) than what you see in the UI (the time stamp).

So maybe just play a little bit around and apply some values to the memory and take a look if your expectations will match (e.g. 1677721600 should match a time around 10:00).